# how to get string outside brackets within brackets regex

Tags: php, regex, brackets

I need help trying to get regex to work with double brackets

currently i have this for the regex

```
(\\[.*?\\])
```

that allows me to get everything inside a bracket,

HOWEVER my string has double brackets

```
[DATA1[OTHERDATA]RUBBISH]
```

the output I get is

```
[DATA1[OTHERDATA]
```

is the a way of getting the full bracket including the bracket inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping things nice and simple. A greedy match should do the trick:

```
/\[(.+)\]/
```

the `.+` will match any character, but it'll stop at the last `]`, so the match will be *"DATA1[OTHERDATA]RUBBISH"*

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zB4fK5/1)

Breakdown is really simple:

- `\[`: Matches literal `[`
- `(.+)`: Match (and capture) all characters - including opening and closing brackets
- `\]`: Match literal `]`

Regardless of how many nested brackets you have the results are the same:

```
[data[foo][bar][eve[n]]more]
//match:
data[foo][bar][eve[n]]more
```

Comment: wonderful! worked perfectly! the other didnt for some reason but worked as a treat :)

Comment: this doesn't recognize missing brackets, for example `[DATA1[OTHERDATA]` will be matched even though the pair is `[OTHERDATA]`, but that largely depends on the OP's use case.  It will also match `[one] other [two]` ( completely as in `one] other [two` ) as seen here https://regex101.com/r/oL4kH5/4

Comment: The greedy dot matching can be used only if there is only one match per string expected and there Iis no need to worry about whether the bracket number is balanced or not.

Comment: @si458: As others point out, if you need to handle more complex scenario's, you may need a more complete approach. I just posted this going on the example you gave us. This regex is able to handle cases where the input is 100% predictable, if that isn't guaranteed to be the case, consider using the expression suggested by wiktor

Answer (score 1):

You may use a recursive regex like

```
\[(?:[^][]++|(?R))*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG8sO2/1)

**Details**:

- `\[` - a literal opening `[`
- `(?:[^][]++|(?R))*` - one or more sequences of:

  - `[^][]++` - 1 or more chars other than `[` and `]` (matched possessively)
  - `|`  - or
  - `(?R)`  - recurse the whole pattern
- `]` - a literal closing bracket.

Comment: Cool mine is also recursive but without using `?R`  You might want to add an outer capture group, not sure if the OP needs the outer brackets but it seems so in the question  "the output I get is `[DATA1[OTHERDATA]`"

Comment: OP gets the text up to the first `]` because of lazy `.*` quantifier. Outer parentheses will add a redundant group in the match.

Comment: My point was the regx `(\[.*?\])` implies to also capture the brackets, wait it might work with preg_match without it, I was thinking in terms of how Regx101 site works, which is slightly different.

Comment: I understand, just it is pointless to wrap a whole pattern with a capturing group in PHP for matching. Regex101 is a help tool, it should not dictate us how to write patterns.

Comment: Yes, I updated my comment, cant test anything in php right now, so I was using that site for it.  lol my bad, its superfluous

Answer (score 0):

In PCRE you can use this recursive regex:

```
$re = '/(
  \[
  ( 
    (?:[^][]+|(?1))*
  )
  \]
)/x';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pF3xQ4/2)

Comment: No need of a subroutine here actually, the shortcut `(?R)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yep:

```
(\[([^\[\]]|(?R))*\])
```

This uses a recursive regex, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rJ8qF9/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it does matched brackets ( recursively )

```
 preg_match('/\[(?:[^\[\]]*+|(?0))*\]/', $string, $match );
```

Shown here

https://regex101.com/r/oL4kH5/2

For example given this

```
  [DATA1[OTHERDATA]RUBBISH] hello [something]
```

You will get these 2 matches

```
  [DATA1[OTHERDATA]RUBBISH]

  [something]
```

It will also differentiate between matched brackets, for example:

```
 [DATA1[OTHERDATA]RUBBISH[hello] hello [something]
```

will return 3 matches

```
 [OTHERDATA]

 [hello]

 [something]
```

This is because the first bracket is unmatched.